# Get JSON data into jQuery.ajax function for calendar plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, silverstripe

I'm working on an event calendar for a SilverStripe site, and I have a function that gets all events for said Calendar and puts them into a JSON data array:

```
  public function getCalendarEvents(){
    $SiteConfig = SiteConfig::current_site_config();
    if(Director::is_ajax()){
        $allEvents = array();

        foreach(CalendarEvents::get() as $Event){
            $date = date('m-d-Y',strtotime($Event->EventDate));

            $linkID = $Event->InternalURLID;
            $doSitetree = SiteTree::get_by_id('SiteTree',$linkID);
            $link = $doSitetree->Link();

            $title =  '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$Event->EventTitle.'</a>';

            $time = date('g:ia',strtotime($Event->EventTime));

            if(!array_key_exists($date, $allEvents)){
            $allEvents[$date] = array(
                array($time, $title)
              );
            }
            else{
                $existingEvents = $allEvents[$date];
                array_push($existingEvents, array(
                    array($time, $title)
                ));
                $allEvents[$date] = $existingEvents;
            }

        }
        return json_encode($allEvents);

    }
    else{
      return CalendarEvents::get();
    }
}
```

This function works fine, but now I need to get the value of $allEvents and place it into the jQuery.ajax function so I can populate a Calendar with the event date (the plugin I'm using is called Calendario). What I want to do is put the JSON data of $allEvents into the variable "caldata" as shown below:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

(function($) {
    var cal = $( '#calendar' ).calendario( {
            onDayClick : function( $el, $contentEl, dateProperties ) {
                for( var key in dateProperties ) {
                    console.log( key + ' = ' + dateProperties[ key ] );
                }
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/getCalendarEvents',
                    context: this
                }).done(function(response) {
                });
            },
            caldata :// [this is where the data for the calendar goes]

        } ),
        $month = $( '#custom-month' ).html( cal.getMonthName() ),
        $year = $( '#custom-year' ).html( cal.getYear() );
    $( '#custom-next' ).on( 'click', function() {
        cal.gotoNextMonth( updateMonthYear );
    } );
    $( '#custom-prev' ).on( 'click', function() {
        cal.gotoPreviousMonth( updateMonthYear );
    } );
    $( '#custom-current' ).on( 'click', function() {
        cal.gotoNow( updateMonthYear );
    } );
    function updateMonthYear() {
        $month.html( cal.getMonthName() );
        $year.html( cal.getYear() );
    }

}(jQuery));
```

I've never used the .ajax function from jQuery before, so I'm not sure how to get the JSON data stored in the $allEvents variable into a variable for caldata.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be requesting for events on each click. Doesn't seem very efficient. Also, data may come back at a later time in the future, while you already initialized the calendario. So you'd need to initialize the calendar when data comes back.
Like this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

(function($) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/getCalendarEvents',
        context: this,
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(response) {

        var cal = $( '#calendar' ).calendario( {
                onDayClick : function( $el, $contentEl, dateProperties ) {
                    for( var key in dateProperties ) {
                        console.log( key + ' = ' + dateProperties[ key ] );
                    }
                },
                caldata : response // [this is where the data for the calendar goes]

            } ),
            $month = $( '#custom-month' ).html( cal.getMonthName() ),
            $year = $( '#custom-year' ).html( cal.getYear() );
        $( '#custom-next' ).on( 'click', function() {
            cal.gotoNextMonth( updateMonthYear );
        } );
        $( '#custom-prev' ).on( 'click', function() {
            cal.gotoPreviousMonth( updateMonthYear );
        } );
        $( '#custom-current' ).on( 'click', function() {
            cal.gotoNow( updateMonthYear );
        } );
        function updateMonthYear() {
            $month.html( cal.getMonthName() );
            $year.html( cal.getYear() );
        }

    });

}(jQuery));
```

Or it would be even better to place the js json data to the template directly and load without the ajax request.

Comment: This seems to be along the lines of what I need. Unfortunately, the data is appearing as "undefined" inside the calendar itself. The undefined values are in the correct dates, but the data is not showing up.